# Standard error of slope estimator

Tags: regression, self-study

Can someone please help explain this. I know the answer is a). Or provide a link with more information.

2. The slope estimator, β1, has a smaller standard error, other things equal, if

   a) there is more variation in the explanatory variable, X.
   b) there is a large variance of the error term, u.
   c) the sample size is smaller.
   d) the intercept, β0, is small.

Answer (score 2):

You can see this by inspecting the formula for the variance of the slope esimate:

$$Var(\hat{\beta}) = \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sum_i(X_i - \bar{X})^2}$$.

Also, use the fact that $$Var(X) = \frac{\sum_i(X_i - \bar{X})^2}{(n-1)} $$ to derive an expression for $Var(\hat{\beta})$ that explicitly includes $Var(X)$.

You can also think about this intuitively: to get a precise estimate of the relationship between $X$ and $Y$, it's better to have $n$ observations on $X \in (0, 1)$ than $n$ observations on $X \in (0.25, 0.75)$